# Консольная пирамида

Tags: python

Как сделать вертикальную пирамиду из * которой можно задать значение(N) которого она будет достигать в центре.

Припустим N=4

и выходит (без точек)

*

**

***.

****.

***.

**

*

Comment: __Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.__ Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и __укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности__ при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Пример:***

```py
def main():
    n = int(input())  # 4

    r = list(range(1, n + 1)) + list(range(n - 1, 0, -1))
    for i in r:
        print('*' * i)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

***stdout:***

```py
*
**
***
****
***
**
*
```